# ReactJS Error: Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mern

I am making a simple TODO App using MERN Stack. But can't able to run because of above mentioned error i.e. Target container is not a DOM element. I checked out whole code but can't able to find its cause or solution. This are the problems. Please help here.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <noscript></noscript>
  <div class="root">  
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {BrowserRouter as Link, Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import TodoList from './components/todo-list';
class App extends Component
{
  render()
  {
    return(
      <Router>
        <div>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a href="/" className="navbar-brand">
              <img src={logo} alt="Logo" height="40" width="40"/>
            </a>
            <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">MERN Stack TO-DO App</Link>
            <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myNavBar">
              <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavBar">
              <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li className="navbar-item">
                  <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Todos</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <Route path="/" exact component={TodoList}></Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

this going to render the React app in a div with id `root`

and in your html file you have a div with class root and no id

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <noscript></noscript>
  <div class="root">  
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

give the div id `root`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <noscript></noscript>
  <div id="root">  
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```